# Is there a way to create a general EventHandler for any System.IndexOutOfRangeException messages?

Tags: c#

For any UnhandledException message in general, I could create a new EventHandler like this:

Program.cs:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException)
}
```

Form.cs:

```
Application.ThreadException += unhandledERROR;

void unhandledERROR(object sender, System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs e) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("ERROR Unhandled Exception");
}
```

Is there also a way to set a general EventHandler when a System.IndexOutOfRangeException message would appear?

Comment: You could simply check the argument in the `unhandledERROR` exception handler. But a much better question is why you think this is useful to begin with -- this event should be used as a last resort to have *some* error handling when you would otherwise crash with no useful information at all, and then a general handler is just as good as anything else. It should not be used as a substitute for actual, proper error handling, that is, making sure `IndexOutOfRangeException` doesn't happen in the first place (it's "[bone-headed](https://ericlippert.com/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/)").

Comment: I agree with @JeroenMostert - An `IndexOutOfRangeException` should not happen in production code.

Comment: A disadvantage this has over a localized `try/catch` is the `try/catch` will only unwind part of the stack, whereas this won't do anything until your application's entire stack has been unwound.  A localized `try/catch` can be recovered from; this, not so much.

Comment: You could try the [FirstChanceException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception?view=netframework-4.8) event handler to catch all exceptions before they are being handled by the code (although i agree with the comments above that this is, probably, not the right approach)

Comment: I have one rare case where it is intended that the application will close forcefully when a specific value in a number array is out of range. I was looking for a way to suppress the message to close the application silently.

Answer (score 0):

You code should contain no `IndexOutOfRangeException` exceptions. There really should be no **unhandled** `IndexOutOfRangeException` exceptions.

---

The correct way to handle `IndexOutOfRangeException` is with `try` and `catch` in the method which could encounter it.

```
try 
{
   // Code that can throw IndexOutOfRangeException 
} 
catch(IndexOutOfRangeException ex) 
{
  // Log, handle, etc.
}
```

Catching exceptions in the last resort handler is too late.